# Deadlock in the semaphore function

Tags: java, multithreading

Question 1:

I was reading into [Hard-core Multi-threading in Java](http://conferences.embarcadero.com/article/32141) and did bump up into the semaphore example below.

```
package com.dswgroup.conferences.borcon.threading;

public class ResourceGovernor {
    private int count;
    private int max;

    public ResourceGovernor(int max) {
        count = 0;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public synchronized void getResource(int numberof) {
        while (true) {
            if ((count + numberof) <= max) {
                count += numberof;
                break;
            }
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (Exception ignored) {}
        }
    }

    public synchronized void freeResource(int numberof) {
        count -= numberof;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

I feel this can lead to deadlock in the below scenario :

All resources are being used and a new thread asks for resources that are not available.
Since it waits inside the synchronized function, the other threads that are using the resources are not able to free the resources as the freeResource function is also synchronized and that they can't enter the function as the waiting thread has taken the object level lock of **ResourceGovernor**

There is another issue that one has not validated if a thread is trying to release more no. of resources than it acquired. But this issue is secondary and can be easily fixed by having the synchronized map of thread name and resource count.

But can i safely say that i diagnosed the 1st problem correctly. (Need to doublecheck since its published for a long time on embarcadero.com)

Question 2:

Can i safely say that a semaphore with only 1 resource has the same behaviour as a mutex lock?

Comment: The validation issue you mentioned may be intentional. The JDK's Semaphore class, for instance, states that "There is no requirement that a thread that releases a permit must have acquired that permit by calling acquire." It's perfectly legal to create a Semaphore with no permits, have one thread try to acquire a permit, and then have another thread "release" a permit (having never acquired one in the first place). In this way, a semaphore can also mimic a CountDownLatch (similar to how a binary semaphore -- 1 permit -- can mimic a mutex).

Comment: Keep in mind that the article is from 2004. All of its content is deprecated today. For a better solution have a look at the concurrent package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> All resources are being used and a new thread asks for resources that are not available. Since it waits inside the synchronized function, the other threads that are using the resources are not able to free the resources as the freeResource function is also synchronized and that they can't enter the function as the waiting thread has taken the object level lock of ResourceGovernor

You've missed the fact that calling `wait()` relinquishes the monitor, so other synchronized code *is* able to execute. From the docs for [`wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29):

> The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the `notify` method or the `notifyAll` method. The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes execution.

For your second question:

> Can I safely say that a semaphore with only 1 resource has the same behaviour as a mutex lock?

I suspect so, although the implementation you've shown doesn't actually stop you from calling `freeResource` several times. It's a slightly odd implementation in that I normally see semaphores counting the number of resources *remaining* rather than the number of resources *taken* - although they're equivalent, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Question 2 : Yes it is similar to mutex. But although mutexes and semaphores have similarities in their implementation, they should always be used differently.  [Nice Explanation Here](http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/RTOS-Mutex-Semaphore)